# How to set a timeout for client http connections in node.js

Tags: node.js

In my node.js application I need my app to communicate to a server. I made an http connection.
I can't find an option in the node.js documentation for setting a timeout on the connection, and it seems that default is 20 seconds. I'd like to increase the timeout to 1 minute for slow connections , Is there a way to do that in node.js?

Comment: Please show the relevant portions of your code so we can see exactly what you're doing.   Questions about code here on stackoverflow should always contain the code you're asking about as that makes it a lot clearer what you're asking and allows us to write an answer that address your precise situation.  From the words in your question, I can't tell if you're talking about setting a timeout on a request to another http server or a timeout on a server, related to the processing of incoming requests.  In addition, how to set a timeout depends upon what library you're using for your connection.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the Help Center here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.